# Good way to start a Visual Studio MSTest project?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, mstest

I'm starting a test project on VS 2017 for a new module of an old software. I'm new to TDD and unit test so I wonder if this is the correct way to do this...

I started by testing how objects are added to the lists of the viewmodel class :

```
[TestClass]
public class RTCM_Config_Test
{
    static RTCM_Bouton input = new RTCM_Bouton();
    static RTCM_Sortie output = new RTCM_Sortie();

    [TestMethod]
    public void CreateConfig()
    {
        //Arrange
        //Act
        RTCM_Config conf = new RTCM_Config();
        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(conf);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void AddNewInputInConfig()
    {
        //Arrange
        RTCM_Config conf = new RTCM_Config();
        //Act
        bool isOk = conf.CreateElements(input);
        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(isOk);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void AddNewOutputInConfig()
    {
        //Arrange
        RTCM_Config conf = new RTCM_Config();
        //Act
        bool isOk = conf.CreateElements(output);
        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(isOk);
    }

}
```

And the CreateElements functions in the view model :

```
    public bool CreateElements(RTCM_Bouton btn)
    {
        if (listButtonsInput == null) return false;

        if (btn == null) return false;

        if (listButtonsInput.Count >= 10) return false;

        return true;

    }

    public bool CreateElements(RTCM_Sortie sortie)
    {
        if (listButtonsOutput == null) return false;

        if (sortie == null) return false;

        if (listButtonsOutput.Count >= 10) return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Before test methods, I declare static input and output objects as test parameters, is it the good way to do ? Or should I declare test object in each test method ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not 100% sure what your asking, but i think your asking how to deal with the parameters your passing, RTCM_Bouton btn &  RTCM_Sortie sortie.

```
public bool CreateElements(RTCM_Bouton btn)
{
    if (listButtonsInput == null) return false;

    if (btn == null) return false;

    if (listButtonsInput.Count >= 10) return false;

    return true;

}
```

This code to me has 4 possible return values or routes, so I would need 4 Tests, typically i follow the naming convention  MethodName_Scenario_ExpectedResult

```
CreateElements_ListButtonsIsNull_ReturnsFalse()
CreateElements_BtnIsNull_ReturnsFalse()
CreateElements_ListButtonsIsNull_ReturnsFalse()
CreateElements_ListInputButtonsIs10orMore_ReturnsTrue()
```

you should use the //arrange section of your test to "Set Up" the test including anything the method needs to run. Create the class and any objects you need to pass with the minimal implementation (just enough to get the test to pass).

So for example

```
[TestMethod]
CreateElements_BtnIsNull_ReturnsFalse()
{
//arrange
RTCM_Config conf = new RTCM_Config();
var RTCM_Bouton btn = null;

//act
var result = conf.CreateElements(btn);

//assert
Assert.IsFalse(result);
}
```

Because RTCM_Bouton needs to be null for some tests and be value for others, i would declare it inside each tests arrange method and not as you have as a global variable.

Comment: Ok thank you for the answer. I will follow your test method naming convention, seems clearer. But for the btn initialisation in the arrange section, there isn't a way to avoid declaration in all test method ? Also, how can I write a test method with a range of values to test ?

Comment: You could declare it in the method, and just initialize it in each test instead. There are arguments for both ways, its personal preference.

If you do it in each test, you get the full picture in the method which some people say is best, if you do it globally or use a SetUp method you save code but some argue you have to look in 2 or 3 places to get the full picture.

Use whatever you personal preference is

Comment: I understood the need of initialisation in each method when I put the test method CreateElements_ListInputIsNull_ReturnsFalse() before the CreateElements_ListInputButtonsIs10orMore_ReturnsFalse() test method. The list is null if I use the same config object.

Answer (score 1):

For your const test object RTCM_Config, you could use a class variable and initialize it in a test initialize method:

```
private RTCM_Config _config;

[TestInitialize]
public void TestInitialize()
{
    _config = new RTCM_Config();
}
```

In my opinion, Anything that reduces code is welcome. You could also introduce a class variable for your button, but you have to rearrange it for each test case.

Two your second question, you can use data driven tests.

```
[DataTestMethod]        
[DataRow(60, 13d)]
[DataRow(1800, 44d)]
public void Testcase(int input, double expected)
{
   //Do your stuff
}
```

Happy coding!